# How to initiate an action conditionally?

Tags: c#, mysql, if-statement

I'm programming a game. I have a mySQL table with data on several soccer teams. One piece of data is the team's reputation. The coach's salary depends on the team's reputation.

In the game there is a combobox containing the names of all teams. So the team you choose will define the coach's salary.  I'd like to do something like this psuedo-code:

```
If ( "the field  comboboxtext reputation" == "worldwide")
{
     coach's salary = 256000
}
```

So how can I accomplish this? If there's a way to do it without using `if`, I'd like to know that too.

Comment: It depends on what you're asking.  Are you asking how to retrieve the value from the combobox?  Or are you asking how to select a value based on what's in the combobox?

Answer (score 1):

This won't really help you, as you basically need a good [C# tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that will cover programming basics, maybe a good book or two, but the code you need should look like something this:

```
long coachSalary;
if (cmbReputation.SelectedText  == "worldwide")
{
  coachSalary = 256000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers are not addressing the problem at hand, unless I'm missing something.

The relationship between a team's reputation and the coaches salary should be stored in a seperate SQL table, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE ReputationSalary (Reputation NVARCHAR(MAX), Salary INT);
INSERT INTO ReputationSalary VALUES ('District', 10000);
INSERT INTO ReputationSalary VALUES ('State', 50000);
INSERT INTO ReputationSalary VALUES ('Nation', 100000);
INSERT INTO ReputationSalary VALUES ('Worldwide', 256000);
```

Then, when a team is selected from the combo box, using the selected team name or team ID, you can look up the coaches salary by using the team name/id to get the team reputation, and then using the `ReputationSalary` table to get the coaches salary.

Answer (score 0):

something like (rough code) :-

```
if(combobox.SelectedText == "worldwide")
{
 coach's salary = 256000;
}
```

if you need to add a else condition also (without using if-else),

```
coach's salary= (combobox.SelectedText=="worldwide")? 256000 : some other value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a more compact version that removed the if and braces, you could use the ternary operator like so:

```
int coachSalary = cmbReputation.SelectedText == "worldwide" ? 256000 : 0;
```

This means that if the first part of the statement, the condition (cmbReputation.SelectedText == "worldwide") is true, coachSalary will be 256000, if not it will be set to 0.

You can see more about the ternary operator here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.110).aspx